# How to use the DisplayMemberPath in a ListView with an ItemContainerStyle?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding, wpf-style

Within a `ListView` control, how to use the `DisplayMemberPath` property when I want to change the `ItemContainerStyle`?

I used a `ListView` control in the `ControlTemplate` of my control and the `DisplayMemberPath` property is set via `Binding` from outside of control.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
          DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Item:" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                            <TextBlock Text=", " />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Is it possible to solve this in **XAML**? How is it solved in the original `ControlTemplate`?

---

I try to solve it with a `MultiValueConverter`, where I bind the Collection Item and `DisplayMemberPath`.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameToValueConverter}">
            <Binding />
            <Binding Path="DisplayMemberPath" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Is it necessary? Or is it the display value already resolved by the original `ListView` control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to solve it by XAML?

No, you use *either* a `DisplayMemberPath` or an `ItemTemplate`/`ItemContainerStyle` but not both.

Also, the `DisplayMemberPath` property is supposed to be set to a `string` that specifies a name of a property of the underlying data class. It is *not* a dependency property that you can bind to.